# "string was not recognized as a valid datetime format" in string date functions?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to deduct one day from my given string date. When i try like below format it shows error.

```
string fdate="12/11/2014"//(dd/MM/yyyy) format
string date2 = (DateTime.Parse(fdate).AddDays(-1)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Please point out the mistake which I did...

Comment: Your example [works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CukXja). Does your computer have regional settings that do not display dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, My system format is "MM/dd/yyyy". but I want date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format. Thats why am using with string.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture` by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might work depending upon the format of system datetime. try to use `ParseExact` method to parse string using format.

```
string fdate = "12/11/2014";
string date2 = (DateTime.ParseExact(fdate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddDays(-1)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

[More information](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/01/05/c.net-little-wonders-the-datetime-tryparse-and-parseexact-methods.aspx)

Comment: yup it works. May I know the difference between Parse and ParseExact??

Comment: `Parse` consider the system format and parse given string and `ParseExact` accept the custom date format as second argument and parse exactly the format you have passed.

Comment: I have a string date in database, that I retrive like **"string todate=dr[1].ToString();"**  and coverts this string date to integer like **"Int todate1=Convert.ToInt32(todate);"** But it shows error **"Input string was not in a correct format"** let me know thereason??

Comment: @BrunoBlane what is the value of `todate` ?

Comment: **21/11/2014**(dd/MM/yyyy) format